# GAE Blob Key Exceeds 500 bytes Maxium Length

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I use blobstore.create_upload_url to uplaod a file to Cloud Storage with a fairly long directory name. The returned blob key exceeds 500 bytes and caused the error showing below.

The work around is to use a shorter directory name.

1. What is the general guidance for the length of directory and filename to generate less-than-500-bytes key?
2. Is it a bug that create_upload_url generates a key that exceed maximum length?

context: python, GAE standard environment

Thanks in advance.

The error message,

```
ValueError: Key name strings must be non-empty strings up to 500 bytes; received AMIfv94PcVablhJ0hpvUKZgaEX3w9Ysm9RLvXRogYwLU373p-DTD6kFkVCJgwfFgq1UIM-xlG2M4GwPWC5lH4XIetUGlD_JoipLmaps9XvTK_1ZnWjUrww86Y6izXLhU-boKHl4G9YxJFi1rNU-9JjJnJ_smXmGp2Aa9OHeNd8imQrxAHjT3bOEQAvoI8MQM3KBlqnh4kVgre7Lf0AQPtb0wiPI42WbyqETQ6QD--BS-ofel0XGt_picz1SN5ECpqXfPctfuE0s40Wq72rzRsSb-UPukdbVDCrdCJOb7ZRnHSGuYtHBzJJR_ilUY9uuMsCPbo4NPOScSfovo2pfcwxjfEs-oFdHLOXu8CRzwLnnzsoNKvGy3VE6mLuDbr-R7cQefybaMQSiKL4VXzEXEVLKP3Yg_1SHeqIRD5xq1pbt1yZcplpJ5jkV-5dVdgBdI9e6NbghwOXhTQQbp7JodYgcdf5bBgemrpIn2ZhMgMrYAEYEe64DeoUBuQNDpmCUVM1z5wxFzrUMSNhayJzMfebMgFJATnppusA

at _ReferenceFromPairs (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py:766)
at _ConstructReference (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py:673)
at positional_wrapper (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py:160)
at reference (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py:546)
at key_to_pb (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py:682)
at async_get (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py:1627)
at _get_tasklet (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py:344)
at _help_tasklet_along (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py:430)
at get (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py:760)
at _help_tasklet_along (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/54c5883f70296ec8_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py:427)
at blob_info_async (/base/data/home/apps/b~suiqui-dev-170002/checklist:checklist-dev.406185416109946132/suiqui/file/models.py:20)
```

UPDATE:

The exception was raised at blobstore.BlobInfo.get_async()

```
@ndb.tasklet
def blob_info_async(self):
  blobinfo = yield blobstore.BlobInfo.get_async(self.blob_key)
  raise ndb.Return(blobinfo)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that raises this error?

Comment: @snakecharmerb add to the main article. thank you.